# Does Laravel have a One-to-zero-or-one Eloquent relation?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Is it possible to use Laravels [HasOne](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relation also as a HasOneOrZero relation?

**Example:**
In the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) the HasOne relation is described between a user and a phone. Would it be possible to use this realtion if each user either has **0** or **1** phone? Or do I need to have a [OneToMany relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) to allow also **0** ?

I am not sure if a [HasOne](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relation might cause any problems if I use it as a *HasOneOrZero* relation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can sue `HasOne` as a `HasOneOrZero` relation.

HasOne relation can be `null`, it's not required to have relation row in database. Just check it while you get it.

Also you may need and like new 5.5 `optional` function.

It works like so:

```
optional($user->phone)->number;
```

If you had phone it will return number, but if it isn't it will be `null` and not `Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to astratyandmitry I would like to add the following that I found out, after I asked myself what is actually the difference between `HasOne` and `HasMany`.

Firstly, they both have the same table structure.

**User table**:

```
id | name
 1 | Alice
 2 | Bob
```

**Phone table:**

```
id | user_id  | phone
 1 |   1      |  123
 2 |   2      |  321
```

The method **hasMany** and **hasOne** in the class `Model` are identically, except for the object that they return:

```
public function hasOne($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
{
    $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();
    $instance = new $related;
    $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();
    return new HasOne($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
}
```

and

```
public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
{
    $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();
    $instance = new $related;
    $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();
    return new HasMany($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
}
```

However, the returned objects (class [`HasOne`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.php) and class [`HasMany`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.php)) only differ in 3 functions:

- getResults()
- initRelation()
- match()

The `getResults()` method is called via the magical `__get()` method whenever the relation is called without brackets (see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2727)) like this

```
$user->phone
```

Here is the `getResults()` method for the class `hasOne`:

```
public function getResults()
{
    return $this->query->first() ?: $this->getDefaultFor($this->parent);
}
```

and thus the output is going to be

[image]

if the relation is declared as `hasOne`

```
public function phone()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
}
```

In contrast the `getResults()` method from the the class `hasMany` is given by:

```
public function getResults()
{
    return $this->query->get();
}
```

And thus the output is an empty collection:

[image]

if the relation is declared as `hasMany`

```
public function phone()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Phone');
}
```

So if there exists no relation row in the database, the `HasOne` relation will return `null` and one can handle it as astratyandmitry described in his post.

Unfortunately, I could not find when the method `initRelation()` or the method `match()` is called.